# $n$-th homotopy group of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a compact, path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I need a reference for the fact that the $n$-th homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$ is trivial.

EDIT: Quite embarrassing. Indeed this is false, as the comment below indicates ($\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$). Should have thought more before posting the question.

Comment: This is not true (so it's hard to give a reference). For example, $S^2$ is a compact path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\pi_3(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$. [See also here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres).

Answer (score 3):

Unless $n \leq 2$ this is not true and simple counterexamples are provided by the $(n-1)$-spheres $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ — which are path-connected and compact, of course.

Indeed, [$\pi_{3}(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_{n}(S^{n-1}) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres).

The cases $n=0,1$ are trivial and for the case $n=2$ there's the following fact:

It turns out that for *all* subsets $X$ of the plane we have $\pi_{k}(X) = 0$ for $k \geq 2$ by a theorem of Andreas Zastrow (1998), [available here](http://at.yorku.ca/i/d/e/b/15.htm).

That reference is distinctly non-trivial and I don't know if there is a simple proof under the hypotheses you're interested in. The statement you ask about does not seem obvious even for relatively nice planar sets, such as the [Hawaiian earring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring), for example.